# org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I am trying to register a simple UDF for extracting date functionality in spark using Scala Luna Eclipse IDE. 
This is my code:
`sqlContext.udf.register("extract", (dateUnit: String, date : String) => udf.extract(dateUnit,date ) )`

```
 def extract(dateUnit : String, date: String) :  String = {
    val splitArray : Array[String] = date.split("-") 
        val result  = dateUnit.toUpperCase() match {
      case "YEAR" => splitArray(0)
      case "MONTH" => splitArray(1)
      case "DAY" => splitArray(2)
      case whoa => "Unexpected case :" + whoa.toString()
    }
    return result ;
  }
```

When I execute this functality an Eclipse console through
as `Select * from  date_dim WHERE d_dom < extract('YEAR', '2015-05-01')  limit 10"`

It throws ans error  as

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Aggregate false, [], [Coalesce(SUM(PartialCount#30L),0) AS count#28L]
 Aggregate true, [], [COUNT(1) AS PartialCount#30L]
  Project []

    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.getObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2030)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1232)
```

I am not able to find out what exactly is the issue, the simple udfs that are defined directly like `sqlContext.udf.register("strLength", (str: String) => str.length() )` 
runs successfully. And the same above function runs successfully through Scala shell in spark. What is the problem here. Am I doing any thing wrong?

Comment: It seems that your splitArray is empty

Comment: whats the fix for this ?